# Win32 Vertical Toolbar Trouble

Tags: c, winapi, toolbar

I'm trying to create a vertical toolbar as per [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/create-vertical-toolbars) instructions but it's not working as expected. My attempt to create the toolbar thus:

```
HIMAGELIST g_hImageList = NULL;
const int ImageListID = 0;
#define TB_TRM_NUM_BUTTONS 2
const int bitmapSize = 16;

const BYTE buttonStyles = 0;

TBBUTTON tbButtons[TB_TRM_NUM_BUTTONS] =
{
    { STD_DELETE, IDM_TRMVIEW_CLEAR, TBSTATE_ENABLED | TBSTATE_WRAP, buttonStyles, {0}, 0, 0},
    { STD_FILEOPEN, IDM_OPEN, TBSTATE_ENABLED | TBSTATE_WRAP, buttonStyles, {0}, 0, 0},
};

// Create the toolbar.
HWND hWndToolbar = CreateWindowEx(0, TOOLBARCLASSNAME, NULL, CCS_VERT | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE , 0, 0, 0, 0, hWndParent, (HMENU)(UINT_PTR)ID, GetModuleHandle(0), NULL);
if (hWndToolbar == NULL)
    return 0;

// Create the image list.
g_hImageList = ImageList_Create(bitmapSize, bitmapSize,   // Dimensions of individual bitmaps.
    ILC_COLOR16 | ILC_MASK,   // Ensures transparent background.
    TB_TRM_NUM_BUTTONS, 0);

// Set the image list.
SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_SETIMAGELIST,
    (WPARAM)ImageListID,
    (LPARAM)g_hImageList);

// Load the button images.
SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_LOADIMAGES,
    (WPARAM)IDB_STD_SMALL_COLOR,
    (LPARAM)HINST_COMMCTRL);

// Add buttons.
SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE, (WPARAM)sizeof(TBBUTTON), 0);
SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_ADDBUTTONS, (WPARAM)TB_TRM_NUM_BUTTONS, (LPARAM)&tbButtons);
```

Creates a toolbar that's too wide:

[image]

When I add `TBSTYLE_WRAPPABLE` the toolbar becomes the correct width but doesn't wrap the buttons vertically:

[image]

To resize the toolbar I'm sending `TB_AUTOSIZE` to the toolbar.

I'd also like to add extended styles to the toolbar:

`SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE, 0, (LPARAM)(TBSTYLE_EX_MIXEDBUTTONS | TBSTYLE_EX_VERTICAL));`

However this sends the toolbar to the otherside of the client area and keeps it horizontal.

How can I get the toolbar to go vertical properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/toolbar-control-and-button-styles):

> TBSTYLE_WRAPABLE: Creates a toolbar that can have multiple lines of
> buttons. Toolbar buttons can "wrap" to the next line when the toolbar
> becomes too narrow to include all buttons on the same line. When the
> toolbar is wrapped, the break will occur on either the rightmost
> separator or the rightmost button if there are no separators on the
> bar. This style must be set to display a vertical toolbar control when
> the toolbar is part of a vertical rebar control. This style cannot be
> combined with `CCS_VERT`.

The key to creating a vertical toolbar is to include CCS_VERT in the window style, and to set the TBSTATE_WRAP style for each button.

The CreateWindowEx function does not have parameters for specifying toolbar size. The toolbar window procedure automatically sets the size and position of the toolbar window. The height is based on the height of the buttons in the toolbar. The width is the same as the width of the parent window's client area. If you want to change the automatic size settings, you could send a [TB_SETBUTTONSIZE message](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/controls/tb-setbuttonsize).

Comment: Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us. Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.